# Problems with an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I am trying to convert an array (of arrays?) to a simple unordered list.
I came up with one solution, but it was very bulky, and I am positive there is a much simpler way to to do it.

This is the array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [projects_id] => 204 [City] => Carrollton ) 
    [1] => Array ( [projects_id] => 2 [City] => Dallas ) 
    [2] => Array ( [projects_id] => 208 [City] => Garland ) 
    [3] => Array ( [projects_id] => 1 [City] => Plano ) 
    [4] => Array ( [projects_id] => 212 [City] => Richardson ) 
)
```

and the list should look something like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Carrollton</a>
    <li><a href="#">Dallas</a>
    <li><a href="#">Garland</a>
    <li><a href="#">Plano</a>    
    <li><a href="#">Richardson</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: So… which way did you try that was bulky?

Comment: I was using a recursion that actually got stuck in an endless loop...

Comment: Why recursion for a simple thing like this? You iterate the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like just about the only way to do it, and it’s pretty straightforward…

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($arr as $item): ?>
        <li><a href="#"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item['City']); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```